# Confused by the wording to this Financial Mathematics Question

Tags: finance, word-problem

The question reads:

> Find the nominal rate per annum convertible quarterly that makes an
>   interest payment of £150 on an initial capital of £1,000, at the end
>   of 2 years.

Could somebody clarify for me whether this 'interest payment' means the accumulated value of the 8 interest payments made over the two years, or otherwise?

I know that this question is very basic but I really need to get to grips with this terminology and also how to approach the question in general.

Comment: It seems like there is one payment of £150, made at the end of $2$ years.

Comment: @saulspatz Does the question not indicate that the rate is payable quarterly? So then there would be eight interest payments?

Comment: The question is very poorly phrased, but my guess would be "starting with an initial balance of $1000$, find the interest rate which, when compounded quarterly, results in a balance of $1150$ at the end of two years. " I would not consider this standard phrasing and I would check with whomever set the problem.

Comment: @lulu I agree. I think you're correct. I will give that a go and see if I arrive at the right answer.

Comment: @user657675 Did you get the right answer?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about quarterly payments being made.  You are asked to the equivalent annual rate of interest, stated as a nominal annual rate payable quarterly.

Comment: @lulu On the contrary, I used to work in this field, and I think it is completely standard phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say "nominal annual rate compounded quarterly," they mean that the rate of interest is stated as $i$ per year, but it really means ${i\over4}$ per quarter.  This gives an effective annual rate greater than $i$, since $$\left(1+{i\over4}\right)^4>1+i$$

In this case, we have $$1000\left(1+{i\over4}\right)^8=1150$$ and you just have to solve for $i$.

If you want to check your work, I get $7.0495\%$

In actuarial literature at least, $i$ would be written as $i^{(4)}$ to indicate a nominal annual rate compounded quarterly, and $i$ reserved for the effective annual rate, so we'd have formula $$i=\left(1+{i\over4}\right)^4-1$$

Comment: Perfect. That completely clears it up for me. I was misinterpreting the question, like you stated in your comment. Thank you.